# Error - Not defined - Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, error-000539

I'm trying to add a part of my filename into a field that i'd created, but it comes with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "Z:\04 - Temp\Charles\NDVI_tempo\NDVI_py3.tbx#Script_NDVIpy3.py", line 50, in
>   
>         File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3019, in
>   CalculateField
>           raise e
>         File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3016, in
>   CalculateField
>           retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CalculateField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table,
>   field, expression, expression_type, code_block), True)))
>         File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   506, in 
>           return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>       arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:  ERROR 000539: Error running expression: test 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       NameError: name 'test' is not defined
>
> ```
> Failed to execute (CalculateField).
> Failed to execute (Script).
> ```

This is the script that i wrote:

```
intershp = 'Z:\\04 - Temp\\Charles\\NDVI_tempo\\NAL\\intershp.shp'

arcpy.AddField_management (intershp, "Data", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

tiff_name = tiff.split("_")[0]
field_name = "{}".format(tiff_name[0:4])

arcpy.CalculateField_management (intershp, "Data", field_name, "", "")
```

Comment: File "", line 1, in NameError: name 'test' is not defined. Where is test coming from i do not see that in the code you posted.

Comment: "test" is a part of the filename, I used "for tiff in rasters" before

Comment: `intershp = r'Z:\04`- you need to raw string your parameter

Comment: It still don't works, the shape haven't any problem at all, the information is from the raster file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the solution!

The expression field couldn't be 'field_name', it has to be "'" + field_name + "'"

Comment: huzzah! I was seconds away posting that answer. Good work :) Here's the documentation where I found it mentioned: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm

Comment: it's good practice to mark your own answer with the green checkmark... better to officially answer your own question than to leave an unanswered question out there.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", i'll mark it! Thanks for the advice